# iPhone 6 Plus issues with using a GLView (device not simulator)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, opengl-es, resolution

At the beginning of the initialization I check to see which device I'm using by testing the height (or width depending on how the user is holding their device). After the device is chosen, the app determines which resolution of the assets to load.

That code I use for checking which device is as follows...

```
if([ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height > [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.width)
{

isIphone4 = ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 480 );

isIphone5 = ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 );
isIphone6 = ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 667 );
isIphone6Plus = ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 736 );
}
else
{
    isIphone4 = ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.width == 480 );

    isIphone5 = ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.width == 568 );
    isIphone6 = ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.width == 667 );
    isIphone6Plus = ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.width == 736 );

}
```

This works perfectly find in accurately detecting which device is being used, except on the physical iPhone 6 Plus.

That however is not the most confusing part, what IS confusing is that it only doesn't work *sometimes*. I've tested it personally on 2 separate iPhone 6 Plus' and the apps work perfectly fine. I've been in contact with a few of my users who have issues and their specs are different, some have AT&T others have Verizon, one has 16GB others have 64GB.

Any body have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. There is a 'Display Zoom' function on the 6Plus which zoomed the display field to a 375 x 667 with a x3 pixel scale factor.

Essentially it's the same size as a iPhone 6 with a x3 scaling.